# Scrape a Dynamic Website using Java with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler, crawler4j

I'm trying to scrape `https://www.rspca.org.uk/findapet#onSubmitSetHere` to get a list of all pets for adoption.

I've built web scrapers before using `crawler4j` but the websites were static.

Since `https://www.rspca.org.uk/findapet#onSubmitSetHere` is not a static website, how can I scrape it? Is it possible? What technologies should I use and how?

**Update:**

When you fill in the search form (Select type of pet and Enter postcode/town or county) in the UI, the results are then displayed below the search box.

[image]

The red is highlighted as the search bar and the black is highlighted as results.

I'm trying to scrape the results and also the content of each result.

I've had a look at the request the browser makes to retrieve results, but from Chrome dev tools it isn't obvious what the request is being made.

Comment: Which info are you trying to scrape from https://www.rspca.org.uk/findapet#onSubmitSetHere

Comment: I'm trying to scrape the results and also the content of each result. I've updated the question with an image of the search query and result. The result are the animals available for adoption.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium to extract information from the DOM once a browser has rendered it, but I think a simpler solution is to use "developer tools" to find the request that the browser makes when the "search" button is clicked, and try to reproduce that.

In this case that makes a POST to `https://www.rspca.org.uk/findapet?p_p_id=petSearch2016_WAR_ptlPetRehomingPortlets&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_petSearch2016_WAR_ptlPetRehomingPortlets_action=search`

The body of the POST request contains a lot of parameters, including `animalType` and `location`. The content-type of the request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

To see these parameters, go to the "Network" tab in chrome dev tools, click on the "findapet" request (it's the first one in the list when I do this), and click on the "payload" tab to see the query string parameters *and* the form parameters (which contains `animalType` and `location`)

The response contains HTML.

I would try making a request to that endpoint and then parsing the HTML in the response.

Comment: I've had a look at the request the browser makes to retrieve results, but from Chrome dev tools it isn't obvious what the request is being made. For example where in the URL or the payload the `animalType` and `location` is being placed.

Comment: I've added more details above.